# How to get discord bot (Python) to wait for embed url messages to have content?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently setting up a bot that posts images directly from a shared twitter link. I got everything technically working but it has a mildly infuriating bug. For the images to be posted in the discord channel, the link has to be posted twice.

Every time the bot detects a message, it'll post the images if the length of the embed message is greater than 0. The problem is the length of the first embed message from a new link is always 0, but the following message with the same link will have the correct message embed length.

The start of the block of code looks like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    print(len(message.embeds))

    if len(message.embeds) > 0:
        # Do stuff
```

So to reiterate if I message a fresh embed url from Twitter, the length will be 0. If I message it again the length will be correctly greater than 0. Is there any way for the initial embed message to have the correct length or to wait for the embed part of the message to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to say without knowing where `on_message` is called, what is the type of `message` nor what your `@client.event` decorator does (a more complete example would help) but your problem could come from the fact that you are using both synchrone and asynchrone (`async`) function in your code.

It might be the case that, on the first execution of `on_message` message is not yet available but is on the second. Did you try to `await` for it?

To understand what is happening under `async` and `await` coroutines in python, I strongly suggest [this article](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) not to run in any anti pattern. The alternative would be to start with a fully synchrone version of your code (without any `async`) to check if the basic logic works